# Can not Install python on mac "BigSur" 3.7.1

Tags: macos, pip, pyenv, macos-big-sur

List versions:
pyenv install --list | grep " 3.[78]"
3.7.0
3.7-dev
3.7.1
3.7.2
3.7.3
3.7.4
3.7.5
3.7.6
3.7.7
3.7.8
3.7.9
3.8.0
3.8-dev
3.8.1
3.8.2
3.8.3
3.8.4
3.8.5
3.8.6

Install python:

```
install 3.7.1
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.7.1.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.7.1...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124748.73048
Results logged to /var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124748.73048.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... checking for --without-gcc... no
checking for --with-icc... no
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124748.73048/Python-3.7.1':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Install python 3.8.6, the same mushrooms:

```
pyenv install 3.8.6
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124910.74631
Results logged to /var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124910.74631.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.2.0
checking for python3.8... python3.8
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/0p/tfnpx69x74z_w4kj6tjkb9tw2v9tpv/T/python-build.20210124124910.74631/Python-3.8.6':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: What is in the logs `/var/folders/**/T/python-build.*.log` ? Do you have a compiler at all?

Comment: Before the new bugged version I had I think. The /var/folders/**/T/python-build.*.log is temporary and has deleted. I'll try to catch it. It works on previous mac versions. Stop worked on "BigSur".

Comment: You definitely won't be able to install 3.7.1 with pyenv because it's not compatible (for building) with MacOS 11 - see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1737#issuecomment-794592631

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're running on bigsur but have an older xcode version - you need to update xcode.